# flutter doctor is running only in the installed bin directory

Tags: flutter

`flutter doctor` was running just fine all these times i have worked on it. I was able to create a project but was not able to run it. `flutter run` literally didn't do anything on my cmd.

So I wanted to make sure everything is fine by running `flutter doctor`, but it showed *'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

I have added the flutter\bin and the Windows\Systems32 path to my environment variables, but it still dosen't work.

Although, flutter commands work just fine on the installed flutter\bin directory.

---

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Can you please check your environment variable again?

Comment: @ChinkySight these are my environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading flutter and substituting the `;` for a `\` in the environment path did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flutter\bin in PATH of user variables.[image]

This is the way i configured flutter and everything is working fine.

Comment: Yes had done that. But somehow replacing ';' with '\' did the job for me as mentioned in my answer